# Routed my website through Amazon-cloudfront, CSS doesn't load now

Tags: css, wordpress, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lightsail

I have a lightsail-bitnami-wordpress site that I've routed through Cloudfront so I can use it's HTTPS/SSL. Once I set it up, the CSS on my site simply stops loading properly. Fonts are wrong, spacing's all over the place, etc.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: You can run open browser's developer tool to see why css aren't loading, Console tab to be specific or Network tab based on that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS files are not loading properly because they point to http instead of https. Open DevConsole (F12 for Chrome) go to console and see if there are any errors. I've had this problem with other CDN's like Google Cloud CDN and CloudFlare and was able to fix it by enabling "Full Strict SLL". I'm not familiar with CloudFront so I googled and found what I think might be a solution: 
**1.** Go into your AWS Console and jump to CloudFront. 
**2.** Find the site you are working on. This isn’t immediately obvious, so look in the Origin column for the domain name or S3 bucket name you used. Click the ID to go into the settings for that CloudFront Distribution. 
**3.** Go to the Behaviors tab and click “Create a Behavior“. You’ll see one behavior already there (“Default  / (*) / S3-Bucket / HTTP and HTTPS”), just ignore that. 

**4.** In “Path Pattern” you’ll want to set the matching rule for the site path you want to effect. In this case we want the whole site, so enter “*”. 
**5.** In “Viewer Protocol Policy” the important work gets done. Select “Redirect HTTP to HTTPS”. 
**6.** Leave everything else as it is. Hit Save. 
**7.** Lastly, make sure that this new rule has a precedence setting of “0”. This means it’s the top CloudFront rule and it will be run before anything else, ensuring HTTPS is selected. [Source](https://cloudconfusing.com/2018/04/28/how-to-redirect-to-https-using-cloudfront/) 
If it doesn't work for you, try adding this to your .htaccess file (if you have one):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Or try to install WordPress plugins that enable Strict SSL Policy, like [WP Force SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-ssl/)